# Mongo C#: Is array field contains element from a given array

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I am using mongodb with the C# driver. I have an object (document) with a property of type `List<ObjectId>` (say `arrProp`).

I want to find all documents that the `arrProp` contains at least one element from a given array (another `List<ObjectId>`).

Is there a way to get the result in a single query?

Comment: Please post some code of what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using driver version 1.5 or later, you can simply use the contains predicate as described in this issue

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-462

If you are using a driver that is pre 1.5, you can use the following extension

ContainsAny (LINQ to MongoDB extension method)

This method is used to test whether an array (or array-like) field or property contains any of the provided values.

```
var query =
    from c in collection.AsQueryable<C>()
    where c.A.ContainsAny(new[] { 1, 2, 3 })
    select c;
// or
var query =
    collection.AsQueryable<C>()
    .Where(c => c.A.ContainsAny(new[] { 1, 2, 3 }));
```